# how do two android apps record at the same time?

Tags: android, c++, c

I use android P (9.0). I need run a voice assistant on any time. When the voice assistant is running, other apps that provide recorder functions cannot run because the PCM device is busy. The tip is:

> cannot open device '/dev/snd/pcmC0D1c': Device or resource busy

Comment: Are you sure you should be using raw PCM devices instead of the [AAudio framework](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/aaudio/aaudio)?

Comment: I used AudioRecorder of  Android Audio Framework  but  the result is same  because of  it must not create two AudioRecorder object at the same time on Android 9

Comment: It seems what you're asking is impossible. You might have to find a workaround.

Comment: At present, all mobile phones on the market can support a voice assistant to run at the same time ,and another recording app can also run

Comment: As far as I am aware, the microphone (and camera too for that matter) can only be accessed by one application at the same time in Android. You might be able to build a layer that copies the signal and distributes it over multiple applications.  On devices running Android 9 (API level 28) or higher, apps running in the background cannot access the microphone.  which might make that tricky

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input